# VBA: Filter multiple columns and select visible cells to copy into a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA, not sure if im getting this right:

Im trying to copy a list of visible cells after filtering 2 columns.
The cells copied will be input into a new excel workbook.
I would like the columns formatting to remain the same after pasting it into the new excel workbook.

Sometimes, The code is able to output a result but it takes really long to run. The output still has the columns which i wanted to hide before copying out the visible cells. Is the sequence of my code wrong?

Also, How do i implement a code to format the column and row size according to the content of the cells?

```
Sub SelectedProducts()
    Dim newBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim rng As Excel.Range


' This hides columns that are not needed in the output

Range("E16").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("G16").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("H16").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("J16").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("M16").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("O16").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("P16").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("Q16").EntireColumn.Hidden = True   
    
'User to select product type to filter by and wether they would like it to be exported
    
    Set newBook = Workbooks.Add
    
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Products").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

    rng.Copy newBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a specific range/table of data you're working with?  Typically you don't want to use something like `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Products").Cells` since that will copy the content from the entire sheet

Comment: @TimWilliams Ive specified the range, so now the code is running much faster, Thanks!  My code is still not hiding the rows before copying out the data into a new worksheet, is there anyway i can hide the columns and then copy out all visible cells?